# Let $f: A\rightarrow A$. Prove that if $(f ◦ g)$ is surjective, then $f$ is surjective.

Tags: functions, proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

Let $f: A\rightarrow A$. Prove that if $(f ◦ g)$ is surjective, then $f$ is surjective.

We know that $(f ◦ g)$ is surjective, so that means that $\forall x\in A, \exists a$ such that $f(g(a)) = x$

Let $y = g(a) \in A$

$\implies f(y) = f(g(a)) = x$

$\implies \forall x\in A, \exists y$ such that $f(y) = x$

$\implies f$ is surjective

Is this proof correct?

Comment: Not really. You must find a pre-image of every **y**, not just those that are of the form **g(a)**

Comment: It is correct.${}$

Comment: No you don't want to start with "Let $y=g(a)$" rather Let $y$ be arbitrary in $A$, then we must find $b$ in $A$ with $y=f(b)$. By the given surjectivity, there exists $a$ in $A$ with $y=f(g(a))$. Let $b=g(a)$, then $f(b)=y$, as desired.

Comment: @Ned: He isn’t *quite* starting with $y=g(a)$; he’s trying to start with $x\in A$ that is the image of $f\circ g(a)$. It’s not written up ideally, but he isn’t making *quite* that error.

Comment: @arryn: He is trying to find a preimage of $x$, not of $y$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin thanks, yes I see. I got confused by the way "Let" was used. He's basically got it right ... good answer below.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have all the pieces, but they are arranged in a way that is making the reader do too much work.  Here is a more typical way of arranging the facts (with a lot of extra text along the way to support apprentice mathematicians).

> Let $x\in A$ be given.  We intend to show that there is some $y\in A$ such that $f(y)=x$.  Since $f\circ g$ is surjective, we may choose $a\in A$ such that $(f\circ g)(a)=f(g(a))=x$.  Since $g(a)\in A$, we may take $y=g(a)$ to be the value we were seeking.  Since $x$ was arbitrarily chosen, $f$ is surjective.

For accessibility, I used the variable names you chose for your proof.  That said, it is more typical and readable for others to use $y$ for a member of a range and $x$ for a member of the domain (so that we would be able to say $f(x)=y$ instead of $f(y)=x$.

Answer (score 0):

Another proof: the image of $f$ restricted to $g(A)$ is $A$, so the image of $f$ contains $A$.  Since the codomain of $f$ is $A$, the image is a subset of $A$, so it follows that the image is $A$.